# Is there a specific methodology for developing mobile applications?

Tags: applications

I'm looking for a methodology made specifically for mobile applications development. I have read about Waterfall and Agile but they are more general. Also, I want a methodology for when there is only one programmer. There is one for only one person: PXP, but its problem is that it lacks in documentation, so I would like to know if there is one more rigorous in that aspect, like for example indicating which diagrams should be made. For example, RUP has some preset documentation formats, but obviously it is not an appropriate methodology in this case.

Comment: (*methodology* may be marketing verbiage for ((pay-)tool supported) *practice*.)

Comment: You might want to ask your question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/